# Inverting matrix of unknown size

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix that has a variable number of columns and rows (but it is always square). The matrix is:

$$
\Gamma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & T & 0 &
   R_j \\
 u \Theta  & \rho  & 0 & 0 & u T
   & 0 & R_j \\
 v \Theta  & 0 & \rho  & 0 & v T
   & 0 & R_j \\
 w \Theta  & 0 & 0 & \rho  & w T
   & 0 & R_j \\
 H \Theta -1 & u \rho  & v \rho  & w \rho  &
   \Omega \rho +H T & \frac{5
   \rho }{3} & R_j \\
 k \Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & k T &
   \rho  & k R_j \\
 Y_i \Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & Y_i
   T & 0 & Y_i R_j+\rho \delta_{ij}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where the indices $i,j$ are the row and column indices respectively. For example, if $i,j={1,2}$ the matrix would look like:

$$
\Gamma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & T & 0 &
   R_1 & R_2 \\
 u \Theta  & \rho  & 0 & 0 & u T
   & 0 & R_1 & R_2 \\
 v \Theta  & 0 & \rho  & 0 & v T
   & 0 & R_1 & R_2 \\
 w \Theta  & 0 & 0 & \rho  & w T
   & 0 & R_1 & R_2 \\
 H \Theta -1 & u \rho  & v \rho  & w \rho  &
   \Omega \rho +H T & \frac{5
   \rho }{3} & R_1 & R_2 \\
 k \Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & k T &
   \rho  & k R_1 & k R_2 \\
 Y_1 \Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & Y_1
   T & 0 & Y_1 R_1+\rho & Y_1 R_2  \\
 Y_2 \Theta  & 0 & 0 & 0 & Y_2
   T & 0 & Y_2 R_1 & Y_2 R_2 + \rho  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The values for $i$ and $j$ can be arbitrary.

When I put this in as is (just treating the subscripts as notation), I get terms divided by the Kronecker delta only which is impossible. Is there a way to invert this and keep it general in terms of $i,j$? The code to enter the matrix is:

```
G = 
  {
    {Θ, 0, 0, 0, T, 0, Rj},
    {Θ*u, ρ, 0, 0, T*u, 0, Rj},
    {Θ*v, 0, ρ, 0, T*v, 0, Rj},
    {Θ*w, 0, 0, ρ, T*w, 0, Rj},
    {Θ*H - 1, ρ*u, ρ*v, ρ*w, T*H + ρ*Ω, 5/3*ρ, Rj},
    {Θ*k, 0, 0, 0, T*k, ρ, Rj*k},
    {Θ*Yi, 0, 0, 0, T*Yi, 0, Rj*Yi + ρ*δ}
  };
Ginv = FullSimplify[Inverse[G]];
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with this? `Ginv.G` gives the right thing. Also, what does "terms divided by the Kronecker delta only" mean, and why is it impossible?

Comment: Mathematica does not know what these symbols mean mathematically. there are just symbols. If you want actual dirac delta, you should use `DiracDelta[]` btw, you might want to add space here "\[Rho]\[Delta]" to make it "\[Rho] \[Delta]" just in case.

Comment: @acl If I look at the `Ginv`, there are terms like $Y_i/\delta_{ij}$ which will be $Y_i/0$ for all but 1 column, which is ill-defined.

Comment: @Nasser But how can I tell Mathematica that $i,j$ are for columns and rows? Without that information, the `DiracDelta[]` wouldn't know what to do either right?

Comment: $\delta$ is meant to be a Kronecker delta?

Comment: @Nasser $\delta$ is the Kronecker Delta, not the Dirac Delta.

Comment: Ok, please then try it again using `KroneckerDelta[]` function. Again, using symbol from the pallet does not mean anything. It is just a symbol.

Comment: I do not understand what you have there, so can't help. I do not know what Y_i supposed to mean. And do not know what R_j suppose to mean. Where did these come from? What is "i" there? what is "j" ?  your question is fully described well to answer it (for me at least)

Comment: @Nasser I added an example, does that help clarify what is happening with $i$ and $j$?

Comment: So when you write eg $R_i Y_i$ you are using Einstein summation notation and would like mathematica to invert the matrix without specifying the dimensions (the limits of the sum)?

Comment: In the example you updated, again where did Y(i) come from? is it just a symbol? or is there an array somewhere Y={....} where the "i" is the index there? Also you say "i" is the row number, but you show Y_1 sitting in the 7th row, not the first row? I am still confused. sorry

Comment: @acl No, it's not exactly summation notation -- $R_i Y_i$ in summation notation would be $R_1 Y_1 + R_2 Y_2$ in the single cell. But I am using an index notation for the rows and columns.

Comment: @Nasser This is for preconditioning the Navier-Stokes equations with $Y_i$ being the mass fraction of a species $i$. So it is a single variable, not an array, and it's 1 because it's the first species, 2 for the second, so on. So I suppose it's not really the row and column number so much as it's the **extra** row and column number

Comment: For every additional species in the system of equations, a row and column gets added to the matrix. And I need the inverse of this matrix. The journal papers all say "This is easily inverted" but provide no details. I can't imagine they have routines for all possible numbers of species which can get up to the hundreds.

Comment: OK yes I see. So maybe clarify the question so someone can have a go? Also the journals are probably referring to numerical inversion, not analytical.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work although I have not tested it thoroughly. Also, it's a rather brute force approach, so I hope someone else will post a more elegant solution.

```
g[0] = 
  {{Θ, 0, 0, 0, T, 0}, 
   {u Θ, ρ, 0, 0, T u, 0}, 
   {v Θ, 0, ρ, 0, T v, 0}, 
   {w Θ, 0, 0, ρ, T w, 0}, 
   {-1 + H Θ, u ρ, v ρ, w ρ, H T + ρ Ω, (5 ρ)/3}, 
   {k Θ, 0,0, 0, k T, ρ}}

upperRight[n_] := Transpose@Table[Join[ConstantArray[R[j], 5], {k R[j]}], {j, n}]

lower[n_] := 
  Table[Join[{Θ*Y[i], 0, 0, 0, T*Y[i], 0}, Table[Y[i] R[j], {j, n}]], {i, n}] /. 
    p : R[x_] Y[x_] :> p + ρ

g[n_] := Join[MapThread[Join, {g[0], upperRight[n]}, 1], lower[n]]

g2 = g[2]
```

> ```
> {{Θ, 0, 0, 0, T, 0, R[1], R[2]}, 
>   {u Θ, ρ, 0, 0, T u, 0, R[1], R[2]}, 
>   {v Θ, 0, ρ, 0, T v, 0, R[1], R[2]}, 
>   {w Θ, 0, 0, ρ, T w, 0, R[1], R[2]}, 
>   {-1 + H Θ, u ρ, v ρ, w ρ, H T + ρ Ω, (5 ρ)/3, R[1], R[2]}, 
>   {k Θ, 0, 0, 0, k T, ρ, k R[1], k R[2]}, 
>   {Θ Y[1], 0, 0, 0, T Y[1], 0, ρ + R[1] Y[1], R[2] Y[1]}, 
>   {Θ Y[2], 0, 0, 0, T Y[2], 0, R[1] Y[2], ρ + R[2] Y[2]}}
> ```

The above is invertible although the result is messy.

```
Short[Inverse[g2], 4]
```

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, by employing [block matrix inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2748), one can derive a general formula for the inverse of $\mathbf \Gamma$. I'll leave the rigorous algebra/justification for other people, but here is how to apply block inversion:

```
emat = {{Θ, 0, 0, 0, T, 0},
        {Θ u, ρ, 0, 0, T u, 0},
        {Θ v, 0, ρ, 0, T v, 0},
        {Θ w, 0, 0, ρ, T w, 0},
        {Θ H - 1, ρ u, ρ v, ρ w, T H + ρ Ω, 5 ρ/3},
        {Θ k, 0, 0, 0, T k, ρ}};

n = 7; (* size of lower right block, change as needed *)

(* upper right *)
ff = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, k}].
     Transpose[Table[ConstantArray[Subscript[R, j], 6], {j, n}]];

(* lower left *)
gg = Table[{Subscript[Y, i] Θ, 0, 0, 0, Subscript[Y, i] T, 0}, {i, n}];

(* lower right *)
hh = Outer[Times, Table[Subscript[Y, i], {i, n}], Table[Subscript[R, j], {j, n}]] +
     ρ IdentityMatrix[n];
```

Generate the full matrix $\mathbf \Gamma$:

```
gmat = ArrayFlatten[{{emat, ff}, {gg, hh}}];
```

Now, assemble the inverse in blocks:

```
einv = Simplify[Inverse[emat]]; (* invert upper left block *)

vec = Simplify[Total[einv.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, k}], {2}]];

dp = Table[Subscript[R, j], {j, n}].Table[Subscript[Y, j], {j, n}];
```

Build $\mathbf \Gamma^{-1}$:

```
ginv = ArrayFlatten[{{einv + Transpose[PadRight[{vec dp/ρ}, {6, 6}]],
                      -Outer[Times, vec, Table[Subscript[R, j], {j, n}]]/ρ},
                     {-Table[PadRight[{Subscript[Y, i]}, 6], {i, n}]/ρ,
                      IdentityMatrix[n]/ρ}}];
```

Check:

```
gmat.ginv == IdentityMatrix[6 + n] // Simplify
   True
```

In symbolic format, the inverse can be expressed as

$$\mathbf\Gamma^{-1}=\small
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3 H T-5 k T-3 \left(u^2+v^2+w^2\right)T+3\rho\Omega}{3(T+\Theta\rho\Omega)}+\frac{\left(T\left(H-u^2+u-v^2+v-w^2+w-1\right)+\rho\Omega\right)\sum_k R_k Y_k}{\rho(\Theta\rho\Omega+T)}&\frac{T u}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega} &\frac{T v}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega}&\frac{T w}{T+\Theta\rho  \Omega}&-\frac{T}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega}&\frac{5T}{3(T+\Theta\rho\Omega)}&-\frac{T\left(H-u^2+u-v^2+v-w^2+w-1\right)+\rho\Omega}{\rho(\Theta\rho\Omega+T)}R_j\\
\frac{(1-u)\sum_k R_k Y_k}{\rho^2}-\frac{u}{\rho}&\frac{1}{\rho} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\frac{u-1}{\rho^2}R_j\\
\frac{(1-v)\sum_k R_k Y_k}{\rho^2}-\frac{v}{\rho} & 0 & \frac{1}{\rho} & 0 & 0 & 0 &\frac{v-1}{\rho^2}R_j\\
\frac{(1-w)\sum_k R_k Y_k}{\rho^2}-\frac{w}{\rho} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\rho} & 0 & 0 &\frac{w-1}{\rho^2}R_j\\
 \frac{-3 H\Theta+5 k\Theta+3\left(u^2+v^2+w^2\right)\Theta+3}{3(T+\Theta\rho\Omega)}+\frac{\left(1-\Theta\left(H-u^2+u-v^2+v-w^2+w-1\right)\right)\sum_k R_k Y_k}{\rho(\Theta\rho\Omega +T)}& -\frac{u\Theta}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega}& -\frac{v\Theta}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega} & -\frac{w\Theta}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega} & \frac{\Theta}{T+\Theta\rho\Omega}& -\frac{5\Theta}{3 (T+\Theta\rho\Omega)}&-\frac{1-\Theta\left(H-u^2+u-v^2+v-w^2+w-1\right)}{\rho(\Theta\rho\Omega +T)}R_j\\
-\frac{k}{\rho} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\rho} & 0 \\
-\frac{Y_i}{\rho} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\delta_{ij}}{\rho}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

The block inversion worked as well as it did because of fortuitous simplifications. For instance, here are some useful identities I determined:

```
einv.ff == Outer[Times, vec, Table[Subscript[R, j], {j, n}]] // Simplify
   True

gg.einv == PadRight[Table[{Subscript[Y, i]}, {i, n}], {n, 6}] // Simplify
   True

Inverse[hh - gg.einv.ff] == IdentityMatrix[n]/ρ // Simplify
   True
```

It was by using these identities that I was able to construct the explicit expression for $\mathbf \Gamma^{-1}$.