# Invert a generic n x n matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

I want to invert a generic n x n matrix. Is it possible to do this with Mathematica?

Consider, as a minimal example, the $n\times n$ matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1n&0&...&0\\0&2n& ... & ...\\ ... & & &0
\\... & ... & 0 & n^2\end{bmatrix}

My attempt was:

```
mat = Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j] i*n, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
mat // MatrixForm
Inverse[mat]
```

However, that generates an error message:

> Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1,n} does not have appropriate bounds.

A related question can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54511/inverting-matrix-of-unknown-size) but it presents a complicated matrix. The solutions are specific to the particular problem, whereas I want to inquire about a general $n \times n$ matrix. The answers should preferably be supported with *minimal* examples.

---

**Edit**: Mathematically, it is clear how to invert a diagonal matrix which is a specific case and a nice example of a trivially non-singular matrix. The aim of this question is to make Mathematica invert a generic $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: "Table" needs a specific bound, you can not iterate from 1 to some unknown number.

Comment: Is there another way to give mathematica my ``generic size'' matrix?

Comment: https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/inverse-of-diagonal-matrix/

Comment: I do not believe there is a generic closed-form expression for the inverse of an arbitrary matrix. You can get there for any given form of a matrix with `Inverse`, though, given the right assumptions on the real/non-zero-ness of the matrix elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

For the given example of `DiagonalMatrix[n*Range[n]]`, the [`Inverse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse.html) is

```
inv[n_Integer?Positive] := inv[n] =
  Inverse@DiagonalMatrix[n*Range[n]]
```

Looking at the first several cases,

```
MatrixForm /@ (inv /@ Range[5])
```

[image]

The `Inverse` is `DiagonalMatrix[1/(n*Range[n])]`.

Checking,

```
And @@ Table[inv[n] == DiagonalMatrix[1/(n*Range[n])], {n, 1, 20}]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** For a generic `DiagonalMatrix`

```
inv2[n_Integer?Positive] := inv[n] =
  Inverse@DiagonalMatrix[Array[a, n]]

MatrixForm /@ (inv2 /@ Range[5])
```

[image]

The `Inverse` is `DiagonalMatrix[1/Array[a, n]]`. Checking,

```
And @@ Table[inv2[n] == DiagonalMatrix[1/Array[a, n]], {n, 1, 20}]

(* True *)
```